# Fazer subset e manter os valores NA

Tags: r

Tenho certeza que há um jeito de fazer subset e manter os valores NA no R.
Porém, quando aplico essa função também está sumindo da minha base os valores NA.
Apenas estou usando a fórmula abaixo:

```
dados1<-data.frame(subset(dados,V2!="CNPJ"))
```

Então está sumindo os valores da V2 que estão em NA.
Qual o melhor jeito de fazer esse subset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jeito que descobri foi colocar o is.na na programação, ou seja:

```
dados1<-data.frame(subset(dados,V2!="CNPJ"|is.na(V2)))
```

Comment: você não precisa chamar a função `data.frame` de novo neste caso. basta `subset(dados,V2!="CNPJ"|is.na(V2))`

Comment: Beleza, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção (talvez mais feia) é usar o subsetting que o operador `[` provê:

```
dados[dados$V2 != "CNPJ",]
```

Essa operação mantém as linhas contendo `NA`.